# displaying friend request list

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I integrated facebook in my android App.In the App i want to get the list of friend requests that is sent to my app to be displayed.My code is in java.I spend so much time in searching a solution.thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     String uri ="https://graph.facebook.com/me/friendrequests";
     HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);
     HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
     HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();
      if (resEntityGet != null) {  
            Log.i("GET ",EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet));
       }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Will return you certain information such as `from`, `to`, `created_time`, etc.
Here's more info https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#friendrequests

**EDIT** It also says that it comes as an "array of objects" so I am asssuming its a JSON format. Use the `JSONTokener` and `JSONObject` to parse in the following manner. Insert this after the line `HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);`

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
for(String line=null;(line = reader.readLine()) != null;){
   builder.append(line).append("\n");
}
JSONTokener jsonTokener=new JSONTokener(builder.toString());
JSONObject finalJson=new JSONObject(jsonTokener)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [THIS](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend_request/) will help you

> Examples
>
> All pending friend requests sent to the current session user (Try this
>   query)
>
> SELECT uid_from, time, message FROM friend_request WHERE uid_to = me()
>
> A pending friend request sent by the current session user to another
>   user
>
> SELECT time, message FROM friend_request WHERE uid_from = me() AND
>   uid_to = "204686"

And here is [a link to FQL (Facebook Query Language)](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)